# jira python customfield

Tags: python, jira, custom-fields

How do you determine the name of a custom field in jira-python?

When I retrieve an issue, my custom fields show up as customfield_xxx

The names on my screen are 'project', 'name', 'due date', etc.
Short of putting a value in each field, then seeing where it appears
when I re-read the issue.

That is I can put 'a' in one of my fields, then read the issue, and find that
customfield_10801 (or whatever) has the value 'a'.  But is there a general
way to find, for example, if my custom field is 'due date', which customfield_xxx
does it get mapped to?

Or, in the JIRA GUI, how would I look up these customfield #'s.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the GUI you can see the custom field id in the html code or url:

- On the admin page where all the custom fields are listed on the row of the custom field you are interested to the right click the gear and click/hover over "Configure". You should see the custom field ID in the URL.

Another way is via the REST API:

- {jira-base-url}/rest/api/2/field
- It's a GET request so just put that url in your browser.

**Update:**

Based on the comments it can be done something like this:

```
# Fetch all fields
allfields=jira.fields()
# Make a map from field name -> field id
nameMap = {field['name']:field['id'] for field in allfields}
# Fetch an issue
issue = jira.issue('ABC-1')
# You can now look up custom fields by name using the map
getattr(issue.fields, nameMap[custom_name])
```

Comment: Thanks LukeSolar.  That works.  I was hoping I could make it programmable.  I use REST in jira-python, and it seems the only data you can get from the customfield_xxx is the id,url, and value.  Not 'name'.

Comment: Your comment about the URL made me realize that the data is at the server level, not project or issue level.  In python, this will make a name-->number dictionary:

Comment: allfields=jira.fields();
    nameMap = {field['name']:field['id']} for field in allfields}

Comment: hey this command helps to get list of all fields of all the projects, 
pls help me to find fields of a particular project..(i know the project key)

Comment: @PaulNelson I updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: this is awesome! one question on it though. What if you use the same field name in two different boards?